# referencing list object by data python

Tags: python, list

Is their any way to directly reference a list object in Python by its data?

In list[{'id':'', 'value':{}},{}] I would like to set the value of an 'id', without iterating the list.

Comment: Your question isn't totally clear.  Give an example of what you want to do.  (Not "set the value of an id" but some try at actual code.)

Comment: I'm trying to weed out duplicate ids in a list of id and value pairs, retaining the last duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't.  You can only reference something with a reference, not data.  In your case:

```
mylist = ['id', value]
```

`mylist[1]` is a reference (a pointer) to a spot somewhere in memory, which contains the data `value`.  You can't reference a data with itself  (well, technically you can, just not in any way that'd make a whole lot of sense).

You can however *get* a reference to the data with

```
mylist[mylist.index(value)]
```

In this case, `mylist.index(value)` gets the index of the first occurrence of `value` without "iterating over the list".  However, you should know that even this way Python is "iterating over the list" under the hood (depending on the implementation of Python).  It's simply how arrays work on a binary level; you must iterate at some point.  (See http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-bytes-bytearray-list-tuple-range)

Comment: The first occurrence is what is desired.  Will a dict iterate in this case?

Answer (score 0):

if given

```
mylist = ['id', value]
```

you can change `value` by assigning to

```
mylist[1] = new_value
```

The question isn't quite clear to me though, sounds though almost you'd want to use a dictionary here rather than a list if you are going to have identifier/value pairs.